# How to make vuex actions wait until a specific action completed to define state

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

Here's my vuex state:

```
state: { id: null }
```

Actions:

```
actions: {
  async getId({ state }) {
    const id = await api.getId()
    commit('setId', id)
  }

  async getById({ state }) {
    return await api.get(id: state.id)
  }
}
```

I have a `mounted()` in my main App.vue file:

```js
// App.vue (parent)
async mounted() {
  // set 'id' globally
  await this.$store.dispatch('getId')
}
```

The problem begins here that I also have another `mounted()` in one of my child views/components:

```js
// Component.vue (child)
async mounted() {
  await this.$store.dispatch('getById', this.$store.state.id)  // <-- notice this
}
```

In the last code, I use `this.$store.state.id` which is null when at the run time. It's because child components created before the parent (App.vue). How do you solve such problems? I chould check if the `id` is null before running `getById` in the mounted. But mounted is called only once when the component is created so if the `id` is null at that time, it'll never dispatch the `getById`...

Please note that this is just an example code. I tried to illustrate the problem with that code.

Answer (score 1):

If the mounted function is relying on a value that is not set, you can prevent the component from mounting in the first place. You can do this by making the rendering of your child component conditional.

Example:

```html
<template>
  <my-child-component v-if="$store.state.id !== null"/>
  <my-loading-spinner v-else />
</template>
```

Usually I implement something a little more complex which watches the state of the API calls (for error handling) and use computed values such as `isLoaded` instead of in-lining the validation in template (for readability)

Comment: What if this component is actually a view? App.vue has a <router-view /> and it's loaded without me explicitly defining it like in your example. Imagine that I need to get some data from the backend to load my Vue app (like checking logged in user info, or some other required data).

Comment: then you might need to nest the component with a "guard" component

Comment: if you can provide an example, I'd be happy to mark your answer. I know how to implement that now but requesting it for further readers.